# Ifup/ifdown problems in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, ifconfig

I am condiguring my eth0 NIC connection through /etc/network/interfaces file.
But each time I changed this file, I ran ifdown eth0 and it responded with waiting for lock on ifstate file and stuck here. So each time I had to restart the system.
Is this due to that I am using Network Manager to configure wlan0 NIC at the same time? How to solve this problem?